# Camel Game, trouble with native distance values

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm trying to write the Camel game using functions instead of so many nested if statements. I think I've done something wrong though, I've had to tinker with the native distance portion a lot as I kept getting into parts where they only got further away not closer. But now after trying to change the randomint values I can never escape them. Any suggestions for improvement are much appreciated! 
Here is my code:

```
import random
def quitGame():
    print("I am guitting now.")
    return True

def status(milesTraveled, thirst, camelTiredness, distanceNativesTraveled, drinks):
print(
    """
    You have traveled %d miles
    Your Camel Status is %d (lower is better)
    You have %d drinks left in your canteen
    Your thirst is %d (lower is better)
    The Natives are %d miles behind you
    """%(milesTraveled,camelTiredness,drinks,thirst,distanceNativesTraveled))

def rest():
    print("The camel is happy")
    distanceN = random.randint(7,14)
    return(distanceN)

def fullSpeed():
    distanceT = random.randint(10,20)
    print("You travel %d miles"%distanceT)
    camelT = random.randint(1,3)
    distanceN = random.randint(7,14)
    return(distanceT,camelT,distanceN)

def moderateSpeed():
    distanceB = random.randint(5,12)
    print("You travel %d miles"%distanceB)
    nativesB = random.randint(7,14)
    return(distanceB,nativesB)

def thirsty(drinksLeft):
    drinksL = drinksLeft - 1
    return(drinksL)

def main():
    choice = ""
    done = False  # loop variable

    #variables for game
    milesTraveled = 0
    thirst = 0
    camelTiredness = 0
    distanceNativesTraveled = -20
    drinks = 5
    print(
    """
    Welcome to the Camel Game!
    You have stolen a camel to make your way across the great Mobi desert.
    The natives want their camel back and are chasing you down. Survive your
    desert trek and out run the native.
    """
    )


while not done:
    findOasis = random.randint(1,20)
    print(
    """
    Here are your choices:

    A - Drink from you canteen.
    B - Ahead moderate speed. 
    C - Ahead full speed. 
    D - Stop and rest for night.
    E - Status check.
    Q - Quit the Game
    """
    )

    choice = input(" Your  choice?\n")

    if choice.upper() == "Q":
        done = quitGame()

    elif findOasis is 1 :
        print("Wow! You've found an Oasis. Your thirst is quenched, canteen topped off, \
and your camel is now well rested and happy.")
        drinks = 5
        thirst = 0
        camelTiredness = 0


    elif choice.upper() == "A":
        if drinks > 0:
            drinks = thirsty(drinks)
            thirst = 0
        else:
            print("Error: Uh oh! No water left.")


    elif choice.upper() == "B":
        milesB,nativesB = moderateSpeed()
        milesTraveled += milesB
        camelTiredness += 1
        thirst += 1
        distanceNativesTraveled += nativesB

    elif choice.upper() == "C":
        milesT,camelTired,nativesT= fullSpeed()
        milesTraveled += milesT
        camelTiredness += camelTired
        distanceNativesTraveled += nativesT
        thirst += 1

    elif choice.upper() == "D":
        distanceT = rest()
        camelTiredness = 0
        distanceNativesTraveled += distanceT

    elif choice.upper() == "E":
        statusCheck = status(milesTraveled, thirst, camelTiredness, distanceNativesTraveled, drinks)

    else:
        print("That was not a correct choice - Enter (A through E or Q)")

    if thirst > 4 and thirst <= 6:
        print("You are thirsty")


    elif thirst > 6:
        print("GAME OVER \nYou died of thirst!")
        done = True

    elif camelTiredness > 5 and camelTiredness <= 8:
        print("Your camel is getting tired")


    elif camelTiredness > 8:
        print("GAME OVER \nYour camel is dead.")
        done = True

    elif distanceNativesTraveled >= 0:
        print("GAME OVER \nThe natives have captured you!")
        done = True

    elif distanceNativesTraveled > -15:
        print("The natives are getting close!")


    elif milesTraveled >= 200:
        print("YOU WIN \nCongrats, you made it across the desert!")
        done = True

# call main
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The game ends when `distanceNativesTraveled >= 0` and yet there's no code at all to decrease `distanceNativesTraveled`. So with every turn `distanceNativesTraveled` keeping increasing, the game is bound to end quickly.

What you really want here is to check if `distanceNativesTraveled` has surpassed `milesTraveled`, so change:

```
elif distanceNativesTraveled >= 0:
```

to:

```
elif distanceNativesTraveled >= milesTraveled:
```

And for the check to see if natives are getting close, change:

```
elif distanceNativesTraveled > -15:
```

to:

```
elif distanceNativesTraveled - milesTraveled > -15:
```

And to properly show the how many miles the natives are behind you, you should show the *difference* between the miles you and the natives traveled, so change:

```
"""%(milesTraveled,camelTiredness,drinks,thirst,distanceNativesTraveled))
```

to:

```
"""%(milesTraveled,camelTiredness,drinks,thirst,milesTraveled - distanceNativesTraveled))
```